# how to specify position to add next note on website?

Tags: reactjs

how to specify the position of next note to be  added
i tried with following code but it is generating randomly even over the previous note .but the next note should not be on the position of previous note.

```
 randomBetween: function (min, max) {
                return min + Math.ceil(Math.random() * max);
  },
 componentWillMount: function () {
      this.style = {
      right: this.randomBetween(0, window.innerWidth - 150) + 'px',
      top: this.randomBetween(0, window.innerHeight - 150) + 'px',
      transform: 'rotate(' + this.randomBetween(-15, 15) + 'deg)' };

   },
```

Comment: Seems like you need a way to track the previous positions then, or just use a specific layout that just puts all the notes next to each other?

Comment: the use of `componentWillMount` is deprecated, so you want to avoid using it.
Your solution is going to be to have one component called `notes` that will handle the position of your notes, and then use an other component that you call `note` that would be the individual notes as children of the `notes` component